# Restore sql server DB between Cumulative updates

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

Respected Sir,

Please I want to know -
Can we restore one database on version-
13.0.5888.11(5001092 Cumulative update 17 (CU17) for SQL Server 2016 Service Pack 2 Latest CU)
To
13.0.5103.6 (4583460 Security update for SQL Server 2016 SP2 GDR: January 12, 2021).

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the only thing that impacts your ability to restore from A to B and then from B to A again would be if the version or edition are different.  The specific patch level should have no bearing on that.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan Fite for answering this. Though Ive read it can have some inconsistency issues as well. So Ive posted it here.

Comment: You should be ok as long as the physical database version wasn't bumped by a CU per [Paul's article](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/sqlskills-sql101-restoring-to-an-earlier-version/). AFAIK, different editions are not a blocker with SQL 2016 SP1 and later due to the common surface area.